# Telnet ant calling the windows bat

Tags: ant, build, telnet

The following ant script used in ant deploy.xml to connect remote windows server and to
call the import.bat in write tag which is currently calling the unix environment and I changed

to call the bat instead of sh.

It is not calling the import cmd in the windows server.

Please help on this how to change this.

```
<telnet userid = "${remote_username}" password = "${remote_password}" server = "${remote_host}">
      <read>></read>
     <write>cd ${remote_ws_path}xx/testSystem</write>
      <read>></read>

  <!-- <write>./import.sh -u ${remote_ws_user} -p ${remote_ws_password} -f ${remote_temp}${rddp_file} | tee ${remote_ws_path}ws/logs/impor_${cu_drop}.log</write> -->

     <write>import.bat -u ${remote_ws_user} -p ${remote_ws_password} -f   ${remote_temp}${rddp_file} | tee ${remote_path}ws/logs/import_${cu_drop}.log</write>
  <read>></read>
</telnet>
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but I do notice that window doesn't have a tee command

Comment: try using [sshexec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task instead